# Setting values and display Text in Android Spinner

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu, spinner

I need help in setting up value and display text in spinner.
as per now I am populating my spinner by array adapter e.g

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

and as far as I know after doing this the display text and the value of spinner at same position is same. The other attribute that I can get from spinner is the position on the item.

now in my case I want to make spinner like the drop down box, which we have in .NET.

which holds a text and value.

where as text is displayed and value is at back end.
so if I change drop down box , I can either use its selected text or value.
but its not happening in android spinner case.

For Example:

> **Text        Value**
>   
>   Cat           10
>   
>   Mountain      5
>   
>   Stone         9
>   
>   Fish          14
>   
>   River         13
>   
>   Loin          17

so from above array I am only displaying non-living objects text, and what i want is that when user select them I get there value i.e. like when Mountain selected i get 5

I hope this example made my question a bit more clear...

thankx

Comment: Another great option if you're not getting it from a persisted datasource and it's just a static array of Display Text and Values is an Enum. Let me know if you're interested and I'll post an answer.

Comment: See this for now tho: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37266810/293280

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Step #1: Create a data model for your text and value pair

Step #2: Extend `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter` to wrap around your data model, overriding `getView()` to return whatever you want to display in the `Spinner` itself

Step #3: On a selection event, use the position to find the corresponding object in your data model, and look up the value

If all you want to display in the `Spinner` is just a text representation of each element in the data model, you can skip the custom `Adapter` -- just use `ArrayAdapter<YourModelClass>` and override `toString()` on `YourModelClass` to return whatever display text you want.

Answer (score 15):

If you dont want to go through creating your own adapter-class you can instead wrap you data up in something that has toString returning what you want to show in the spinner. I use a class like this:

```
public class TextItemPair<T> {
    private String text;
    private T item;
    public TextItemPair(String text, T item) {
            this.text = text;
            this.item = item;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public T getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getText();
    }
}
```

And when the spinner changes:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    YourTypeHere t = ((TextItemPair<YourTypeHere>)spinner.getItemAtPosition(position)).getItem();
}
```

Comment: just this is enough if you have textvalue custom class  @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getText();
    }