# Android create a spinner with items that have a hidden value and display some text?

Tags: android

I'm sure this is asked plenty and i've found some questions on here similar but none really got the coin dropping for me. I'm hoping someone can help me out.

What I want to do is present the user with a dropdown (spinner) with a list of flavours Vanilla, Chocolate, Strawberry.

When the user selected the flavour of their choice the I want the value of Strawberry which is 10 to be returned.

```
Strawberry = 10
Chocolate = 20
Vanilla = 30
```

I come from a vb.net background so finding this incredibly hard to work with the fact i need arrayadapters and stuff to do it?

Could anyone simplify things for me and perhaps share some code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i think this post will help you [Android: How to bind spinner to custom object list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625249/android-how-to-bind-spinner-to-custom-object-list)

this question author has the same requirement as you

Comment: Thanks that solution posted in there looks perfect!

Comment: @L2wis happy that it helped you. could you please mark it as answer so that it will help others also

Comment: Absolutely! I've not actually implemented it yet but I think i will be able to thanks to your link.

Answer (score 15):

you can try this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> SpinerAdapter;
         String[] arrayItems = {"Strawberry","Chocolate","Vanilla"};
         final int[] actualValues={10,20,30}; 

        SpinerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayItems);
        spinner.setAdapter(SpinerAdapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                int thePrice=actualValues[ arg2];

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can instantiate an ArrayAdapter typed with you data object type.
The Spinner will then hold your complete data object instead of a String.
Values displayed will be determined by the toString() method of your data objects.

Example:

```
List<Project> allProjects = ...;

    ArrayAdapter<Project> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Project>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,allProjects.toArray(new Project[allProjects.size()]));
    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

...

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Log.i(AppConst.TAG, "ItemSelected:" + position + " id: " + id);
    Project selectedProject = (Project)getSpinner().getSelectedItem();
    currentTask = selectedProject.toString();
    Log.i(AppConst.TAG, "Selected Project:" + selectedProject.getId());
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a great tip! Thanks.  I was able to simply override toString() in my custom class and get the value to display exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

here is the code:

```
        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Spinner spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,quantity));
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                if(arg2==0){
                textView.setText("Strawberry = 10");
            }else if(arg2==1){
                textView.setText("Chocolate = 20");
            }else if(arg2==2){
                textView.setText("Vanilla = 30");
            }

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }
        });

String[] quantity={"Strawberry","Chocolate","Vanilla"};
```

and xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

### Use Enums to neatly wrap everything up in.

Using Enums keeps things clean and provides you with a Object Oriented interface without having to persist the data. And by the looks of it, you are using constant values for each of your "flavours" (e.g. `Strawberry = 10`).

So, start by creating a "Package" or directory called `enums`. We'll keep all your `Enums` in there.

Then create a new file in there called `Flavour`:

**enums/Flavour.java**

```
public enum Flavour {

    STRAWBERRY("Strawberry", 10),
    CHOCOLATE("Chocolate", 20),
    VANILLA("Vanilla", 30);

    private String displayString;
    private int value;

    private Flavour ( String displayString, int value) {
        this.displayString = displayString;
        this.value   = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return displayString;
    }

    public String displayString() { return displayString; }

    public String value() { return value; }

    public static Flavour fromDisplayString( String displayString) {

        if ( displayString != null ) {
            for ( Flavour flavour : Flavour.values() ) {
                if ( displayString.equalsIgnoreCase( flavour.displayString ) ) {
                    return flavour;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Flavour with display string " + displayString + " found");

    }

    public static Flavour fromValue( int value) {
        if (value != null) {
            for (Flavour flavour : Flavour.values()) {
                if (value.equals(flavour.value)) {
                    return flavour;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Flavour with value " + value + " found");
    }

}
```

I'll leave the rest of the adapter stuff up to you to do but the key pieces are this:

- Use `Flavour.values()` to get the array of Flavours for your Spinner Adapter.
- The `toString()` will automatically be called when the Spinner is populating so your display string (or whatever you return in that method) will be what's displayed.
- When saving the value, you can use this:

  ```
  ( (Flavour) spinner.getSelectedItem() ).value();
  ```